# iOS:Fetch all gmail Contacts into your iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gdata

I have gone through gdata-objectivec-client but i am not getting any way to include 
gdata api(framework) into my iPhone app as Gdata.framework  file is in red color means missing in downloaded source code

I have also downloaded sample code(http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) but none of them is running on simulator

Please help me with any Tutorial or sample code 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi Dinesh I'm not sure whether u have solved your problem or not but to overcome from this issue what you can do is open the Xcode Home window select the second option named Connect to repository and paste the link into Location then click on checkout. Select the destination where you want to import it. And you are done. 
It worked pretty well for me. Hope it helps